# (Another) text formatting method with word wrapping in Java

Tags: java, strings, reinventing-the-wheel

Please take a look at my code for (simply) formatting/wrapping a text. Is there something to improve?

Here are the properties the method should have: (updated)

- Every space character (i.e. `" "` or `"\n"`, etc.) that occurs at least once should be replaced by exactly one space character.
- A line of text should not be longer than `maxLen` characters.
- Long words at the end of a line should be inserted into the next line ((soft) word wrap).
- The `'\n'` character should be used as the line separator.
- Lines should not be filled up entirely with spaces.

```java
package text;

public class Util {
  public static String formatText(String string, final int maxLen, final boolean softWordWrap) {
    if (string == null) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("string is null");
    }
    if (maxLen <= 0) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("maxLen must be > 0");
    }

    final StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    final char ls = '\n';
    final String text = string.replaceAll("\\s+", " ");
    final String[] words = text.split(" ");

    int wordIndex = 0;
    int lineIndex = 0;
    while (wordIndex < words.length) {
      final String word = words[wordIndex++];
      final int before = result.length();
      if (lineIndex + word.length() <= maxLen) {
        // word will fit
        result.append(word);
      } else if (softWordWrap && word.length() <= maxLen) {
        // do not split word
        --wordIndex;
        int len = maxLen - lineIndex;
        lineIndex += len;
      } else {
        // split word (even if softWordWrap == true)
        int splitIndex = maxLen - lineIndex;
        String newWord1 = word.substring(0, splitIndex);
        String newWord2 = word.substring(splitIndex);
        result.append(newWord1);
        --wordIndex;
        words[wordIndex] = newWord2;
      }

      if (wordIndex >= words.length) {
        break;
      }

      lineIndex += result.length() - before;
      if (lineIndex < maxLen) {
        result.append(' ');
        ++lineIndex;
      }

      if (lineIndex >= maxLen) {
        result.append(ls);
        lineIndex = 0;
      }
    }

    return result.toString();
  }
}
```